# How to run the same function in parallel with different arguments?

Tags: python

I want to run the same function multiple times, each time with different arguments whilst using multithreading or multiprocessing.  This is my code so far:

```
import threading
import time

def infiniteloop1(a):
    while True:
        print(a)
        time.sleep(1)


thread1 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1('aaa'))
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1('bbb'))
thread2.start()
```

**Expected output:**

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb
```

I.e. each block of `aaa` and `bbb` will be printed at the same time every second.

**Actual output:**
only aaa is printed every second

Answer (score 6):

`threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1('aaa'))` does not call `infiniteloop1` on a separate thread.

`threading.Thread`'s `target` argument should be a callable. Instead, `infiniteloop1('aaa')` evaluates (=calls) `infiniteloop1` even before `threading.Thread` is called, and `thread1.start` is never even reached.

You would have found this out on yourself if `infiniteloop1` did not actually create an infinite loop. For example, if it was to simply return the argument it got:

```
def infiniteloop1(a):
    return a

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1('aaa'))
```

the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` would have been raised. This is because `infiniteloop1('aaa')` is evaluated to `'aaa'` which is then passed to 
`threading.Thread` as `target`.

Instead, provide a callable to  `threading.Thread` and the arguments for it separately with the `args` kwarg (and keep in mind that it expects an iterable, so a single string argument should be passed as a one-tuple).

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1, args=('aaa',))
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1, args=('bbb',))
thread2.start()
```

output:

```
aaa
bbb
bbbaaa  
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb
aaabbb

aaabbb

bbb
aaa
aaabbb
```